# error passing json in rails (JSON::ParserError) "757: unexpected token in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make a request from another url that calls back to my railsapp with a json responce and i get the following error in the process

```
  757: unexpected token at 'https://voguepay.com/?v_transaction_id=demo-1355137288&type=json'
  json (1.7.5) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

my controllers action is bellow

```
  def get_response
    @transaction_id = params[:transaction_id]
    response = JSON.parse("https://voguepay.com/?v_transaction_id=#{@transaction_id}&type=json").body
  end
```

any idea what i am doing wrong

I tried the url directly in my console window and i got the same error
the url is
https://voguepay.com/?v_transaction_id=demo-1345109950&type=json

Comment: You're trying to parse a URL. `JSON.parse(open("...").body)` if you're using `open-uri` You need to read the response, you're not even sending a request.

Comment: @injekt just showed you how.

Comment: This question does not require a down vote whoever did

Comment: if i use open, i get no such file or directory, if i use open-uri, i get wrong number of argument(0 for 3). Any one that knows the answer so pls just create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use [typhoeus gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/typhoeus) and [yajl-ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/yajl-ruby) gem. It all works fine for me and decided to share my solution below.

```
  def notify
    @transaction_id = params[:transaction_id]
    hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new
    request = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://voguepay.com/?v_transaction_id=#{@transaction_id}&type=json")
    request.on_complete do |response|
      transaction = Yajl::Parser.parse(response.body)
    end
    hydra.queue(request)
    hydra.run
  end
```